# Database Migration Task fails to load the data into the source database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, dms

I have created PostgreSQL (target) RDS on AWS , did schema conversion using SCT and now I am trying to move data using Data Migration task from database (DB2) placed at EC2 instance (source) to target DB. The data is not loading and task is giving following error:

> Last Error ODBC general error. Task error notification received from subtask 1, thread 0 [reptask/replicationtask.c:2800] [1022502] Error executing source loop; Stream component failed at subtask 1, component st_1_5D3OUPDVTS3BLNMSQGEXI7ARKY ; Stream component 'st_1_5D3OUPDVTS3BLNMSQGEXI7ARKY' terminated [reptask/replicationtask.c:2807] [1022502] Stop Reason RECOVERABLE_ERROR Error Level RECOVERABLE

Comment: Got any solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same error and the issue was related to database user rights for `REPLICATION CLIENT` and `REPLICATION SLAVE` as mentioned in AWS Documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.MySQL.html#CHAP_Source.MySQL.Prerequisites

I resolved it by setting the above mentioned `REPLICATION` rights using the following statements in MySQL (replacing {dbusername} with the actual database user name which was being used in DMS Endpoint):

`GRANT REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* to {dbusername}@'%';`

`GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* to {dbusername}@'%';`